# setting gutter style not working singularitygs 1.2.1

Tags: singularitygs

I'm using singularitygs 1.2.1, compass (1.0.0.alpha.19), sass (3.3.7, 3.2.19)

when I add:

```
@include add-gutter(3px);
  @include sgs-change('gutter styles', 'fixed');
```

it completely breaks the gutters
also getting this warning on the command line:
WARNING: DEPRECATION: In order to remove global variable naming conflicts, Singularity's settings have been moved into the single `$singularity` variable. Please refer to our documentation (https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki) on how to update your settings. In the next version of Singularity, this warning will be removed. split has been returned.

if I remove the sgs-change and just use:

```
@include add-gutter(3px);
```

I get:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 201 of _background-grid.scss: Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.)
```

I followed the wiki on how to add fixed width gutters, what am I missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Two things are happening here:

1. The docs were incorrect, it should be `@include add-gutter-style('fixed')`. They have since been updated.
2. The error you're getting is from using the background grid with `px` gutters. This should produce a grid with no visible gutter, but rather alternating color columns. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues?state=open) so we can fix it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I added @include add-gutter-style('fixed');
and it did give me alternating color columns for the background.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I added include add-gutter-style('fixed');
and it did give me alternating color columns for the background. I tried include add-gutter(20px); without the background grid, but added a bg color to the regions and couldn't get the gutters to show at all. when you say the docs have been updated, what docs are you referring to? I've been using the wiki and I don't see the update.

Comment: Fixed gutters are output as padding, so you're not going to see them if you apply backgrounds directly to your columns.
There have been a handful of changes between 1.x.x and 2.x.x and those syntax changes have been noted where appropriate in the docs.